# Getting' no reply received within timeout' despite the required channel exists

Tags: spring-integration

I am using spring integration in my project. The following is the web.xml code which loads the required config files:

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:TestService/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value/>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Here is my `applicationContext.xml` file:

```
<int:annotation-config/>
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.test"/>
  <mvc:annotation-driven />

  <import resource="JobDesigner-springintegration.xml"/>    
  <import resource="DataSourceConfiguration.xml"/>

   <!-- Inbound/Outbound Channels -->
    <int:channel id="httpJobRequest" />
    <int:channel id="httpJobResponse" />

    <int-http:inbound-gateway id="inboundhttpJobRequestGateway"     
        supported-methods="GET, POST" 
        request-channel="httpJobRequest"
        reply-channel="httpJobResponse"     
        path="/jobdesigner"
        reply-timeout="90000"
        error-channel="cs-exceptionHandlingChannel" >

        <int-http:header name="${headerNames.jobName}" expression="#requestParams.src[0]"/>

    </int-http:inbound-gateway>

    <!-- Http Rest Input Buffered Channel -->
    <int:bridge input-channel="httpJobRequest"      output-channel = "jobDesignerInputChannel"  />

</beans>
```

here is my `JobDesigner-springintegration.xml` file which loads all the files having spring integration channels.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:int-xml="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml/spring-integration-xml.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc/spring-integration-jdbc.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd ">

    <import resource="spring-integration/Jobs/*.xml"/>

    <!-- map of namespace prefix to URI -->
    <util:map id="xmlMessageNamespace">
        <entry key="SOAP" value="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />
    </util:map>

    <bean id="customerServProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                 <value>classpath:TestService/property-files/*.properties</value>     
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                 <value>classpath:TestService/property-files/*.properties</value>     
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <int:channel id="jobDesignerInputChannel" />
    <int:channel id="cs-exceptionHandlingChannel" />

    <bean id="msgHandler" class="com.org.cs.test.jobs.PQMessageHandler" />


    <bean id="headerMapper" class="org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper">   
        <property name="inboundHeaderNames" value="*" />
        <property name="outboundHeaderNames" value="HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, Use-200-on-204-response" />
        <property name="userDefinedHeaderPrefix" value="" />
    </bean>

    <int:payload-type-router input-channel="jobDesignerInputChannel"  default-output-channel="xmlMessageChannel">
        <int:mapping type="java.util.HashMap" channel="multipartMessageChannel" />
    </int:payload-type-router>


    <int:chain input-channel="xmlMessageChannel" >
        <int:service-activator  ref="msgHandler" method="test" />

        <int-xml:xpath-header-enricher default-overwrite="true"  should-skip-nulls="true"  >
            <int-xml:header name="${headerNames.legacySystem}"  xpath-expression="//LegacySystem"  evaluation-type="STRING_RESULT"  overwrite="true" />   
        </int-xml:xpath-header-enricher>        


        <int:header-enricher>
            <int:header name="${headerNames.businessArea}" expression="#xpath(payload, '//businessArea/Code', 'boolean') ? null : #xpath(payload, '//businessArea')"/>
        </int:header-enricher>

        <int:router expression="${routing.jobChannel}"/>
    </int:chain>

    <int:chain input-channel="multipartMessageChannel" >
        <int:router expression="${routing.jobChannel}"/>
    </int:chain>    


    <int:chain input-channel="cs-exceptionHandlingChannel">
        <!-- Service Activator to handle the errors --> 
        <int:service-activator  ref="msgHandler" method="handleError" />

        <!-- Router to routing the error messages to appropriate job channel for xsl transormation -->      
        <int:router expression="${routing.jobErrorChannel}"/>
    </int:chain>           
</beans>
```

The following properties are loaded from the properties file:

```
routing.jobChannel=headers.jobDesignerJobName+'-InputChannel'
routing.jobErrorChannel=headers.jobDesignerJobName+'-XsltTransformInputChannel'
```

The idea is to route the message to appropriate channel based on the value of `"headers.jobDesignerJobName"`. All the channels are accessed successfully when they are deployed in Jboss server after accessing the home page of our application. But, weirdly, no channel is accessible if we directly try to invoke the channel with http request. I found by debugging log messages that the message is reached till `<int:service-activator  ref="msgHandler" method="test" />`, but after that it is not able to trigger the `headers.jobDesignerJobName+'InputChannel'` though `headers.jobDesignerJobName` has the valid value. Just getting the error:`no reply received within timeout`

My test() method is just a dummy method which added for debugging purpose:

```
public Message<?> test(Message<?> inMessage){
        return inMessage;

    }
```

What's going wrong here? 
Is it something to do with the JBOSS session management? If that's the case, the `applicationContext.xml` file shouldn't be accessible at all as per my understanding. Can anybody tell the reason?

We are using Maven for dependency management.Spring Messaging jar is pulled transitively by Spring Integration.

```
+- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:jar:5.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:5.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.2:compile
```

Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that your `msgHandler.test` method returns something? If it is `void` or returns `null`, the flow stops and there indeed is not going to happen any reply. Therefore an `<int-http:inbound-gateway>` fails with the mentioned error.

You don't show an important code, e.g. who subscribes to the `jobDesignerInputChannel`. Who sends messages into the `httpJobResponse`. That `msgHandler.test` etc. Everything what is really related to the problem. But you show a standard `web.xml`. How is it related to the problem, please?

**UPDATE**

It is hard to understand what is going on in your so custom configuration.

I suggest you to enable `<message-history>` and log all the traffic via `<wire-tap>`. So, that way you'll see in logs how your message is passing components and where is really a problem.

See Docs for more info:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/#message-history

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/#channel-wiretap

Comment: Thanks for the response and I apologize for the confusion. I have updated the question and now you can know who subscribes `jobDesignerInputChannel`. It is expected that the response is sent to `httpJobResponse` after publishing the message  to the desired channel and doing some other operations with that message. Here the problem is that the message is not even  published to the desired channel after `msgHandler.test` . Please let me know if I confuse you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer. Unfortunately nothing obvious with your current code...

Comment: I am getting the error`SpringDispatcherServlet threw exception: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.WireTap.postSend(Lorg/springframework/messaging/Message;Lorg/springframework/messaging/MessageChannel;Z)V`  after adding the code changes suggested by you. Is this something related to versions conflict? I am using all the spring jars of version `5.0.6.RELEASE`. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: I think your Spring Framework Messaging is in wrong version. Not sure how you manage versions, but it is definitely an issue of mismatched artifacts. You may also consider do not have Spring Framework dependencies, but rely on those pulled transitively by Spring Integration.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We are using Maven for dependency management.Spring Messaging jar is pulled transitively by Spring Integration only. I added the dependency tree( related to spring messaging jar) information to the question. Any other suggestion please.

Comment: Then you have something else in your classpath which overrides a correct version at runtime...

Comment: I could able to resolve the jar conflict and get the additional trace and found that there is some issue with the xml that I am sending as part of the rest call. Thank you very much for your help in figuring out the problem. Plus one for your help!!